# in php array fetch all rows from mysql database into the single table td?

Tags: php, mysql, database

in php `array fetch all rows`from mysql database and all values are showing into the `single table td?` i Want results like this?

```
1) Small
2) Large
3) Medium
```

now problem is that all values displaying into `single table td` i want to display all of these values into `separately table td`

**Query Function**

```
function get_size($id){
$result=mysql_query("SELECT size FROM mywishlist order by id") 
or die("My Wish Size Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$results = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$results[] = stripslashes($row['size'])."<br />";
}
return $results;
}

<td><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  
font-size:15px; color:#000;">
<?php 
foreach($size as $sizes) {
echo $sizes; }
?></font><input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $size;?>" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($size as $sizes) { ?>
    <td><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:15px; color:#000;">
        <?php echo $sizes; ?> 
        </font><input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $size; ?>" /></td>  
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($sizes as $size) { ?>
   <td>
     <font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:15px; color:#000;">
       <input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $size; ?>" />
     </font>
   </td>  
<?php } ?>
```